# Why is my JDBC call failing to return anything?

Tags: java, jdbc

I can connect the JDBC driver connect to the database. Break points show it has a connection id and the fields are properly filled, but after execution of the select statement, no rows are returned even though data is in the database and the SQL call works properly in workbench.  It only returns field names without any data.

Why aren't any rows being returned?

Code:

```
public class DBConnect {

    private static Connection conn;
    public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/efwalter";
    public static String user = "root";
    public static String pass = "XXXXXXXXX";
    private PreparedStatement prep;

    public void open_Con() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            infoBox(ex.toString(), "ERROR");
        }
    }

    public ResultSet get_data(String SQL) {
        try {
            prep = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM efwalter.impact_tests");
            ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
            return rs;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            infoBox(ex.toString(), "ERROR");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void close_Con() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            infoBox(ex.toString(), "ERROR");
        }
    }

    public void infoBox(String infoMessage, String location) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + location, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Code where ResultSet is accessed:

```
 public void searchFired(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException {
   try{
        DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
        db.open_Con();
        ResultSet rs = db.get_data();
        db.close_Con();

        while (rs.next())
        {
           study_struct study = new study_struct();
           ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
           study.setStudy_number(rs.getInt(1));
           row.add(rs.getString(1));
           study.setCustomer_id(rs.getInt(2));
           study.setShop_order(rs.getInt(3));
           study.setProduct(rs.getString(4));
           study.setGmax_results(rs.getString(5));
           study.setGmax_average(rs.getDouble(6));
           study.setHic_results(rs.getString(7));
           study.setHic_average(rs.getDouble(8));
           study.setSensor_data_x(rs.getString(9));
           study.setSensor_data_y(rs.getString(10));
           study.setDescription(rs.getString(11));
           study.setGauge(rs.getString(12));
           study.setAppraiser(rs.getString(13));
           study.setStudy_name(rs.getString(14));
           row.add(rs.getString(14));
           study.setTimestamp(rs.getString(15));
           row.add(rs.getString(15));
           study.setWeight(rs.getString(16));
           found_studies.add(study);
           search_table.add(row);
        }

        resultsGrid.setItems(search_table);
   }
   catch (SQLException ex)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was this handy box to the right titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. There was also a preview of your question shown underneath where you were typing so you could make sure things looked right. This is your 12th question, there is really no excuse for not formatting correctly at this point.

Comment: Okay, so that tells us how you opening, integrating and closing the database connection, which is all good, but it doesn't tell us HOW you are using it.

Comment: @ T.J. : I'll read though that

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I put up the code that is using the resultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code calling your `get_data()` method, which you should post, I will suspect you need to extract your data from your `ResultSet` before you close the `connection`.

Here is an example of how to work this appropriately:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Fprepex.htm

EDIT: Based on your newly-posted code:

```
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    db.open_Con();
    ResultSet rs = db.get_data();
    db.close_Con();
```

**You are closing the connection right after you get the rows**, this closes your ResultSet and flushes your data.

Iterate through the data, THEN call `db.close_Con()`.

What you **really** want is a take on this:

```
CustomDataContainer data = new CustomDataContainer();
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement prep = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {

    conn = getConnection(); // method returns a connection to your DB
    prep = conn.prepareStatement(STRING_REPRESENTING_YOUR_STATEMENT);
    rs = prep.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {

       data.addData(rs.getString(1));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // re-throw ex
} finally {

    try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    try { prep.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}

return data;
```

Comment: when i try there isnt any data in there. After looking through the ResultSet struct in a break the field "currentRow" is set to -1, which i presume means it does not contain any data.

Comment: `currentRow` is just the current row the `ResultSet` is iterating on.  It starts at -1.  You need to cycle through it using the `next()` method.  The Java API will help you here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: @user1003131 HOW are you retrieving the values??

Comment: Apparently my initial assessment was 100% correct; you are closing the connection before iterating the ResultSet.  I don't know how that warrants a negative vote on my answer.

Comment: i didn't give it a negative answer...im still working through it. But i used my vote to bump it back up

Comment: @user1003131 From you update, this answer is correct.

Comment: I updated my answer with a barebones example for you to work from.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to JoshDM's answer...

You need to make sure that you keep the connection open until you are finished with it, but you should, also, make every attempt to ensure that the connection is closed properly...

```
public void searchFired(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // This needs to be declared out side the try/catch so we can
    // reference it later...
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    try {
        // Open the connection
        db.open_Con();
        // Get the data
        ResultSet rs = db.get_data();

        // Process the data
        while (rs.next()) {
            //...Trimmed for space ;)
        }

        resultsGrid.setItems(search_table);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // It's never a good idea to "consume" exceptions,
        // if you're not going to re-throw it, you should it at least
        // log it
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Make every attempt to close the connection now we're finished with it...
        try {
            db.close_Con();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```